# Turn on "non-sorted-cites" for a single \cite command

Tags: citing, amsrefs

When using the command `\cites`, `amsrefs` usually sorts the citation labels and then compresses ranges of three or more consecutive labels into a range. This is typically the behaviour I would like to see; nevertheless, I would sometimes want `amsrefs` not to follow this behaviour. Is there a command like `\citesnonsorted` that I can use or easily define to allow me to achieve this?

I know there's a package option `non-sorted-cites`, but that turns ordering (and range compressing) off globally.